# How to extract an element (href) with selenium and save to a variable

Tags: python, selenium

I am looking to extract the url of the first link in a Youtube search without having to load the video page.

```
import urllib
from selenium import webdriver
song='burning bridges'
songsearch=urllib.parse.quote_plus(song)
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=%s+lyrics' % songsearch)
urlinc = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text(song)

print (urlinc)
print ('done')
driver.quit()
```

href="/watch?v=R8tVZ_QfYe4" class="yt-uix-sessionlink yt-uix-tile-link yt-ui-ellipsis yt-ui-ellipsis-2       spf-link " data-sessionlink="itct=CB0Q3DAYACITCLqBt--IyMkCFVPRvgodYRkCZij0JFIWYnVybmluZyBicmlkZ2VzIGx5cmljcw" title="OneRepublic-Burning Bridges (Lyrics) HD NATIVE" rel="spf-prefetch" aria-describedby="description-id-231739" dir="ltr">OneRepublic-Burning Bridges (Lyrics) HD NATIVE

output:

```
selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="9bf01a91206f82d9462b6803c5084aa5", element="0.22866418561898172-1")

done
```

Comment: Uh...Do you want to get the url of that link?

Comment: Precisely! I want the url of the link without opening the page. I'm sure it is a simple fix however it has eluded me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
>>> urlinc.get_attribute('href')
'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=omhYPjksUy8'
>>>
```